# Linux head y tail

Tags: linux, bash

Quiero, de una lista que tengo generada con un *script*, quedarme con los elementos que se encuentren entre la posición **7** y **15** (por ejemplo). Estoy intentando hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
cat /etc/passwd | tail -n +$FT_LINE1 | head -n $FT_LINE2-$FT_LINE1
```

**donde** FT_LINE1=7 y FT_LINE2=15 están almacenados en las *variables de entorno*. El problema me surge con el `head`, que **no realiza la operación de resta**.

**Mi salida:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La salida que quiero:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo pongo ahora mismo

Comment: No hace falta, no me di cuenta que era el passwd, perdona, ahora te pongo una respuesta

Comment: Aps, pues suerte que la has puesto, jeje, pense que lo querias por las columnas, no por lineas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```sh
cat /etc/passwd2 | head -n 15 | tail -n +7
```

Básicamente se trata de decírselo al reves. Con el primer pipe con esto:

```
head -n 15
```

vamos a imprimir todo hasta la linea 15, pero con el segundo pipe con esto:

```
tail -n +7
```

le estamos diciendo que muestre todas las líneas a partir de la posición 7 del anterior pipe.

Tal como se explica en su página [`man`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/tail.1.es#n):

> -n, --líneas=[+]NUM
>
> muestra las últimas NUM líneas, por defecto mostraría 10; o emplea -n +NUM para mostrar a partir de la línea NUM

Aunque en este caso el aporte sobre el uso del signo `+` es del propio OP en los comentarios, no mio.

Comment: Me ha funcionado la solución, solo un pequeño cambio: después de hacer el head me quedo con los 15 primeros elementos. Si a este conjunto le hago un tail de 7 positivo (tail -n +7) me lo da por correcto y me devuelve lo que estoy buscando. Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Pues tienes toda la razón del mundo! Gracias, voy a modificar mi respuesta con tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Puedes evitar usar `head` y `tail` y usar `sed` o  `awk`:

```
$ sed -n '7,15p' /etc/passwd
```

Donde `-n`es para evitar imprimir por defecto, y `p` es para imprimir en ese rango de líneas.

```
$ awk 'NR>=7 && NR<=15' /etc/passwd
```

Donde `NR` es el número de registro, y le pedimos que imprima entre el número de registro 7 y 15.

Así evitas usar tres programas (cat, tail, y head), tan sólo usando uno.